# “Keyset does not exist” when using SignData function with RSA

Tags: certificates, key-management, rsa

"Keyset does not exist". I know that there are tons of question about this error, but mine is totally different.

I'm not gona use the key from windows certificate store, but load the public key & private key from 2 bare strings, using method "fromXMLString".

```
rsa.fromXMLString "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>......"
```

then

```
rsa.SignData buffer, algSHA1
```

and Booom! : "Keyset does not exist"

Can someone please tell me that using the rsa key pair from 2 xmlStrings is innocent and it entirely does not relate to windows certificate store? I have my own approach of storing & loading certificate/keys.

PS: The other answers for questions on this error told questioner to set correct permission for private key in cert-store. But in my case, I used no private key file in that store, right ?

Comment: And I assume you used the ToXMLString function for those bare strings?

Comment: I've tried it that way, but here I have these 2 strings from some conversions. I'm sure that the 2 keys are correct cause they do the encrypt/decrypt stuffs well. Just the sign stuff is stucking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about how to use a programming interface, not about the security of this interface.

Comment: This question should be tagged with a programming language/library, and asked on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and I find solution now. 
You need use the same rsa that you used to generate the signature to generate a public key and provite key for all to use, then use this public Key & private key  for all other action: encrypt,decrypt,verify, you will not see this error.